# ConanException: Package require 'qt' not used in components requires

Tags: qt, cmake, conan

I've created a project which has two targets, `core.dll` and `runner.exe`.
`Core.dll` depends on `Qt5::Core`.
`Runner.exe` depends on `core.dll`.

Also I've created a conan recipe `conanfile.py`.

I defined `qt` in `requirements:`

```
def requirements(self):
        self.requires("qt/e5.12.4@mikhail/testing", private=False)
```

In `package_info` I use `components`:

```
def package_info(self):
    self.cpp_info.components["core"].libs = ["core"]
    self.cpp_info.components["core"].requires = ["qt"]
    self.cpp_info.components["runner"].requires = ["core"]
```

On build I have error:

> File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\conans\client\installer.py",
> line 571, in _call_package_info
> raise ConanException("%s package_info(): %s" % (str(conanfile), e)) conans.errors.ConanException: lexer/1.0.0@mikhail/testing
> package_info(): **Package require 'qt' not used in components requires**

I assume I miss some detail. I would appreciate any advice or reference to read about.

**conanfile.py**

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake, tools

import os.path

class LexerConan(ConanFile):
    name = "lexer"
    license = "Proprietary"
    author = "Mikhail"
    topics = ("lexer")
    version = "1.0.0"

    settings = {
        "os": ["Windows"],
        "compiler": None,
        "build_type": None,
        "arch": None
    }
    options = {"shared": [True, False]}
    default_options = {
        "shared": False
    }
    
    generators = "cmake_paths"
    exports_sources = "*"
    no_copy_source = True

    def build_requirements(self):
        self.build_requires("cmake-toolkit/1.0.0@mikhail/stable")
        self.build_requires("cmake/3.17.1")

    def requirements(self):
        self.requires("qt/e5.12.4@mikhail/testing", private=False)

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.definitions["VERSION"] = self.version
        cmake.definitions["CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE"] = os.path.join(self.build_folder, "conan_paths.cmake")
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()
        
    def package(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.install()

    def package_info(self): #ERROR ConanException: Package require 'qt' not used in components requires
        self.cpp_info.components["core"].libs = ["core"]
        self.cpp_info.components["core"].requires = ["qt"]
        self.cpp_info.components["runner"].requires = ["core"]
```

**If you need more details I created a reference [project](https://github.com/MGritsenko/Example_CMake_Conan) on GitHub**

Comment: Only local components can be used without a namespace. Otherwise, you must add it. For instance: qt::qt, boost::boost, ...

Comment: quick hint: the way to constraint settings in the recipe with the ``settings = {"os": ["Windows"],`` definition is not recommended any longer. It will most likely be removed in Conan 2.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to use namespace qt::qt.

```
self.cpp_info.components["core"].requires = ["qt::qt"]
```